# Search / Filter list all in one

Tags: search, lists, search-results, maps

One of interfaces im working in, has a interesting problem.
On the same screen i have a list on the left, a map on the right and a search bar on top.
On previous mobile interfaces, the search bar would search and filter the list, or in the map screen would search for a address, as we don't see the list and map on the same screen as we do now.

How, with only one search bar, typing should filter the list and search the map?
my initial idea is to create a results area with a tabbed list for address and other results,
any ideas?

would it be better to use 2 different input search areas for map and list? or one main results list?

Comment: Hello User, is the map static or changing location following search?

Comment: akitae, it would be helpful if you can add mockups of your design.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify it in your question, I am assuming that the list content is not necessarily related to the map search result. In other words, it might be map content related previously saved (like favorite locations) or even not related to the map at all.

Following the previous suggestion from @prince about showing the dropdown list as the user searches, you could explicitly separete the results presented in the dropdown list to help user selecting what was her search intention.

For instance, a simple line separator dividing the results with list results at the top and map results at the bottom, might do the trick:

[image]

If you find that the users are having difficulties in identifying what results are related to what (list or map), you might need to add two nice icons at their repective first results or other visual indication.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best if , once the user start typing something in the search bar, the list will drop down from the search bar and show the possible results, much like google search. Having a list on the left is, in my opinion, a waste of space because the list is, i assume, only required to show the current results which wont possibly be very long. So i suggest you show the list only when the user starts typing in the search bar.

Comment: interesting idea, how would that work with a more dynamic result list? i mean, one type of result will send the user to a detail page, the other type of result will pan the map to a specific localization.

Comment: make a scroll the for the list of results am i right..

Comment: @akitae Ultimately, isnt it the value in the list that you want to show in the map. S when user enters the place to search for, the required results will come in the drop down list and once the user confirms a value in the dropdown list, then you change the location on the map.